# Auctions with affiliation

Tags: self-study, auctions

This problem is an example given in Vijay Krishna's *Auction Theory* (2nd Edition, Chapter-6, Example 6.2). The problem is as follows:

Suppose $S_1,S_2$, and $T $ are uniformly and independently distributed on $[0,1]$. There are two bidders.Bidder 1 receives the signal $X1=S1+T$,and bidder 2 receives the signal $X_2=S_2+T$. The object has a common value for both the bidders, $V=(X_1+X_2)/2$.

Now, we are required to find out the bidding strategy for a first price auction. The equilibrium bidding function is given as $\beta(x)=\int_0^xv(y,y) \,dL(y|x)$. $L(y|x)$ is further equal to $\exp(-\int_y^x\,\frac{g(t|t)}{G(t|t)}\,dt)$.

I have four questions:

> 1. How are $X_1$ and $X_2$ affiliated?
> 2. How is $\frac{g(t|t)}{G(t|t)}$ calculated in this example?
> 3. How do I find the joint density of $X_1$ and $X_2$?
> 4. How do I find the conditional density of $X_2$ given that $X_1=x$?

Comment: Can anybody help with this?

Comment: What do you mean by " how are $X_1$ and $X_2$ affiliated"? Affiliation is a form of positive correlation. There is a definition in the book. Moreover, Krishna usually uses $G$ as the cdf of the highest order statistic and $g$ as its density.

Comment: @Bayesian Let me rephrase my query. Say there are two random variables(rvs) $X_1,X_2$. We say that the rvs are affiliated, if a higher value of one rv may lead to statistically higher value of the other. Mathematically, we say that the joint density is log-supermodular. My question is, how did the author deduce that $X_1,X_2$ are affiliated, given that there is no information about their joint density. Moreover, in the next step he has calculated $\frac{g(t|t)}{G(t|t)}$, which I think cannot be calculated without the joint density of $X_1,X_2$.

Comment: Also, the joint density of $X_1$ and $Y_1$ given in Figure 6.2 of the book, which I'm not able to figure out.

Comment: I can back out the joint density and conditional denisty from the fact that each of the three components ($S_1,S_2,T$) is uniformly distributed. I will put that into an answer later. Let me know if that is what you mean.

Comment: Yes, the main problem that I'm facing is how to find the joint density. I'll be grateful if you could write an answer for the same.

Comment: I will reformulate your question and then answer it.
Let me know if what I wrote sounds reasonable to you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Roughly speaking, $X_1$ and $X_2$ are affiliated because they have the common component $T$. That is, if $X_1$ is large, $X_2$ tends to be large as well, because a large $X_1$ makes a large $T$ likelier than without this information.
   The variables are affiliated if for the joint density $f_{X_1,X_2}$ 
   $$f_{X_1,X_2} (x',y)  f_{X_1,X_2} (x,y') \geq f_{X_1,X_2} (x,y) f_{X_1,X_2} (x',y') \quad \forall x'\geq y, y'\geq y,$$
   which here holds with equality. That is, they are weakly affiliated. See below.
2. In Krishna's book $G$ (resp. $g$) is usually the CDF (resp. density) of the highest value among the other bidders, $Y_1$. Here, there is only one other bidder such that $Y_1=X_2$ and $g(y|x) = f_{X_2|X_1=x}(y |x)$.

Now, my answers only help you if you know how to find the joint density.
Here is what we want to find:

[image]
 So, how to get there?

3. $S_1,S_2, T$ are i.i.d. draws from the uniform distribution.
   Let us first consider the joint CDF of $X_1, X_2$ conditional on $T=t$. That is easy, because they are independent now! Once we have this conditional CDF, we use that
   $$F_{X_1,X_2} (x,y) = \int_0^1 F_{X_1,X_2|T=t}(x,y|t) f_T (t) dt,$$
   where $f_T(t)= 1$ if $t\in [0,1]$ and $f_T(t)= 0$ otherwise.
   Then, we take derivatives with respect to $x$ and $y$ to find $f_{X_1,X_2}(x,y)$. This should look like what Krishna has in his picture or alternatively, like the function in the appendix of [Avery (ReStud 1998)](https://academic.oup.com/restud/article-abstract/65/2/185/1580729), where the example is from (I guess). 
   These calculations are cumbersome work with a bunch of case distinctions and thus it is easy to mess up, but you start with 
   $$F_{X_1,X_2|T=t}(x,y|t) = \mbox{Pr}(X_1<x,X_2<y|T=t) = \mbox{Pr}(S_1<x-t,S_2<y-t)$$ 
   and then pay attention to the support of the uniform distribution. The CDF is $F_{S_1}(s)=s$ for $s\in [0,1]$ and zero for smaller $s$ and one for larger $s$.

Let us take an exemplary region, $y>x>1$:
$$F_{X_1,X_2}(x,y) = \int_0^{x-1} 1 dt + \int_{x-1}^{y-1}(x-t)dt+ \int_{y-1}^1 (x-t)(y-t)dt,$$
which gives us something of which Mathematica says it has a derivateive $\partial x \partial y$ equal to $2-y$. Now, we can verify one of the regions of Krishna's graphic.
One more for fun, if $x<y<1$,
$$f_{X_1,X_2}(x,y) = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x \partial y} \left( \int_0^x (x-t)(y-t) dt + \int^1_x 0 dt \right) = x.$$
And so on. Now, you can go back to my reply 1.

4. The conditional density of is given by the equation
   $$f_{X_1,X_2} (x,y) = f_{X_1|X_2=y} (x|y) f_{X_2} (y),$$
   where
   $$f_{X_2}(y) = \begin{cases} y &\mbox{if } y \in [0,1] \\
   2-y &\mbox{if } y \in [1,2],
   \end{cases} $$
   which follows from the fact that $X_2 =S_2+T$, and $S_2$ and $T$ are independently uniformly distributed. You get there with [convolution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357672/density-of-sum-of-two-uniform-random-variables-0-1). What you get should look like this plot from the Avery paper[image]

Then, you integrate to find $G(y|x)$ and go back to my reply 2.

Comment: Disclaimer: I am not a probability theorist - far from it. This is how I approached this example from scratch. I put in some work, because I was curious - I actually taught this example once and I took Krishna's density for granted without knowing how to get there. I would be happy to make this answer more detailed so I know where to come back to if I have to teach this again and forget how to do it.

Comment: Thanks. The expression $F_{X_1,X_2|T=t}(x,y|t) = \mbox{Pr}(X_1<x,X_2<y|T=t) = \mbox{Pr}(S_1<x-t,S_2<y-t)$ was something I was looking for. From here it is relatively easy to work out the solution.